# HadoopDb Java Program

Tags: hadoop

first of all thanks for showing interest.

I'm Adarsh Sharma presently working on Hadoop Technologies such as Hive, Hadoop, HadoopDB , Hbase etc.
I have configured HadoopDB on the Hadoop Cluster of 3 nodes with Postgres as the database layer.

I load a table website_master containing 3 columns in hadoopDB in chunked form.
I see the results from Hive by quering.

But now I want to write a program that fetches data of website_master from hadoopDb which is postgres tables in different databases.

Can U Explain What should I do . I read the HadoopDb Quick Start Guide but it doesn't help me.

Comment: Which requirements do you mean? Hardware? Programming skills? Software environment? License?

Comment: I'm not Felix Kling but I believe to fetch data you have to write a HadoopDB job.

Comment: please stop duplicating the posts; they will be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see the http://hadoop.apache.org/